# Почему так активно задаются вопросы на мете?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, мета

Так как голоса могут быть не только за то что участнику это нравится, но также бывает и голосование. Из-за этого репутация не повышается. Но вопросы здесь задаются также активно, как и на самом сайте. Почему так?

Comment: Потому что не все участники сидят на сайте только ради репутации? :)

Comment: @PashaPash Но здесь вопросы только по самому сайту, здесь нет конкурсов, вопросов по программированию ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: А почему вы сами задали тут два вопроса за час?

Comment: Ну, появились вопросы по сайту.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> - Ну, появились вопросы по сайту.
>   [@VerNick](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8060/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5#comment33251_8060)

Comment: Ну ладно)))))))

Comment: @Kromster, ну не, так не смотрится совсем, лучше оставить как есть :-)

Comment: Ну не хотите, как хотите. Но без контекста реально вводит в заблуждение

Comment: Замените ссылку на https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8060/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5#comment34032_8060 чтоб действующая была.

Answer (score -2):

### Ответ найден.

Дело в том, что когда задаешь вопросы на реальных сайтах с репутацией, постоянно боишься, что заминусят, найдут дубликат, закроют, удалят, и может даже заблокируют возможность задавать вопросы. Здесь же ты можешь задать вопрос с любым заголовком, абсолютно не боясь, что произойдет. <strike>Делай что хочешь.</strike> Но все равно надо следить за вопросами(для новичков).


Но все равно я так и не понял, зачем здесь отвечают.

Comment: Блокировки на задавание вопросов работают и на мете тоже. Просто количество минусов, которое нужно нахватать для попадания в них, на мете установлено выше.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Значительно выше.

Comment: *"Но все равно я так и не понял, зачем здесь отвечают."* - А вы сами зачем сейчас ответили? ;-)

Comment: @Kromster Ну блин, вопрос то мой.

Comment: ну и что, что ваш? для себя вы ответ знаете, зачем его для всех остальных запостили? ))))

Comment: @Kromster Высказываю свое мнение :)

Comment: Вот и остальные высказывают. Людей хлебом не корми, дай мнение свое повысказывать )